# Analytic function derivate over an annulus

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, analytic-functions

I'm trying to decide if exist an analytic function over the annulus
$A = z \in\mathbb{C} ; 1 < |z| < 2$  such that the derivative is equal to $(z^2 +1)^{-1}$

My attempt is using the derivate of $\arctan (z)$ that is:
$\tan^{-1}(z) =\frac{1}{2i} \log(\frac{1+iz}{1-iz}) $ and prove that I cannot define a continuous branch on the annulus

Comment: If you mean $\frac{1}{z^2+1} =\frac{1}{2i}( \frac{1}{z+i}-\frac{1}{z-i})$ then the answer is yes, its primitive is analytic on $|z| > 1$.

Comment: Could you please tell me explicitly which is the primitive of the function, Im confused.

Comment: It is $\frac{1}{2i} (\log(z+i) - \log(z-i))$ with the principal branch of $\log$ : $\log(r e^{it}) = \ln r+it$ for $r > 0, t \in [-\pi,\pi)$. When doing a ccw rotation the $2i\pi$ added to $\log(z+i)$ cancels the $-2i\pi$ added to $-\log(z-i)$ so the function of $|z| > 1$ doesn't have a branch cut

Answer (score 1):

The function has a primitive in $|z|>1$ and you can define the primitive explicitly by $F(z)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n} \frac 1 {z^{2n-1}(2n-1)}$. Note that the series convrges uniformly on compact subsets of $\{z:|z|>1\}$ so $F$ is indeed a holomorphic function in this region. You can compute its derivative by differentiating term by term and you get  $F'(z)=-\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n} z^{-2n}$. But the given function $f$ can we written as $f(z)=\frac 1 {z^{2}} (1+\frac 1 {z^{2}})^{-1}$ and expanding $(1+\frac 1 {z^{2}})^{-1}$ we see that $F'=f$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. Take any loop $\gamma$ in that annulus. Then the winding numbers of $\gamma$ with respect to both $i$ and $-i$ are the same. Besides, $\operatorname{res}_{z=\pm i}\frac1{z^2+1}=\mp\frac i2$. Therefore, by the residue theorem, $\int_\gamma\frac{\mathrm dz}{z^2+1}=0$. Since this happens for every loop, your functions has a primitive: just fix a point $z_0\in A$, for each $w\in A$ consider a path $\eta$ going from $z_0$ to $w$ and define$$F(w)=\int_\eta\frac{\mathrm dz}{z^2+1}.$$